# Customize fonts in context menus and dialogs

Tags: unity, gnome, fonts, unity-tweak-tool

So I changed all my desktop fonts to 'Ubuntu Light' using unity-tweak-tool and I am running Iris Dark Theme, but the fonts in Nautilus, dialogs and context menus are unaffected (see screenshots) How can I change this? If I need to change it within the theme, what file of the theme would I have to edit?

Fonts in context menus of applications ok (Firefox context menu):

[image]

But fonts on nautilus and desktop unaffected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it now: the different appearance results from the theme itself. When a non sans-serif font is selected by using unity-tweak-tool, it is displayed consistently throughout the whole desktop. This seems to affect only sans serif fonts, most noticeably with the Ubuntu Light font. I can live with that now ;)

Answer (score 0):

open Unity Tweak Tool.
goto Fonts settings.
change "Default font" and "Window title font" to Ubuntu Light then logoff and login again and try check whether you are getting it or not.
comment if you have any issue

Comment: I changed ALL the fonts in unity tweak tool to say Ubuntu Light. I am getting the correct font for Window Title. I get it anywhere except Nautilus and desktop-related context menus.
Here are the values set by unity-tweak

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name
'Ubuntu Light 11'

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 
'Ubuntu Light 11'

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name
'Ubuntu Mono 13'

gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font
'Ubuntu Light 11'

Comment: @mario2k14 i dont know then. i can set context menu fonts on my machine Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @mario2k14 i recommend you to stop wasting your time on this and accept the answer i gave. :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @edward torvalds!! I have found the reason for it now, see  below :)